# Why does my Technic Launcher crash when play any modpacks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack, minecraft-hexxit

When I open Technic and my favorite modpack is either Hexxit or the other one with rockets (I forgot the name), I can only play it for 7 minutes at the most before it lags REALLY bad and then crashes.

I only have 32 bit java though. My computer is normally pretty fast after I get completely logged on.

Why does technic keep crashing? Could it be because I only have 32 bit java?

Comment: how much RAM do you have? a lot of technic mods are VERY demanding of RAM and CPU, you may need to allocate more to the client.

Comment: I don't know if i will be able to answer that question until tommorow because I'm in school and i have a SMT Blast at 7:00-11:00 lol

Comment: Is it a laptop?  Does it slow down on any other games?  Sounds like it might be overheating.

Comment: Could be running out of RAM, could be overheating. The launcher can set the RAM allocated to Minecraft; if the game goes over that though, it'll just crash.

Comment: It is a laptop but it doesent slow down on any other games at all. I usually get like 115 fps on vanilla minecraft, and when i enter any Technic modpack, it starts at around 60. It doesn't overheat either. Right when i turn it on i wait for it to load with the lid down (sometimes) so it doesn't overheat and then I go on Technic, and it still starts at 60 fps.

Comment: My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite A505 with Windows 7 Professional. Processor-Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M330 @ 2.13GHz RAM- 4.00 GB 3.87 GB left System type-64-bit Operating System. Oh, and what is a Service Pack? I have Service Pack 1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't provide tech support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score -2):

Uselessly it crashes when I start a mod pack and it says bad graphics card: update graphics card. So if it says that somewhere in the error you need to update your graphics card.

Comment: How do i update my Graphics Card? lol

Comment: @soulreaper he probably means graphics card drivers (the software that makes your graphics card work). Find out who made your graphics card and google "[graphics card manufacturer] driver update", and try downloading new drivers